# Let $|G|$ be an abelian group and let $H = \{g \in G : |g| \text{ divides } 12 \}.$ Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $|G|$ be an abelian group and let $H = \{g \in G : |g| \text{ divides } 12 \}.$  Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I know that I have to show that $a,b \in H \Rightarrow ab^{-1} \in H$ or $(ab \in H \land a^{-1} \in H).$  But I can't figure out how $|a|$ and $|b|$ dividing $12$ relates to $|ab|$ or $|ab^{-1}|$ dividing $12$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The crucial observation is that $|g|$ divides $12$ if and only if $g^{12} = e$.
 With this, it is simple to verify the requirements for subgroup:

- $e \in H$ because $e^{12}=e$.
- $a \in H \implies a^{-1} \in H$ because $(a^{-1})^{12}=(a^{12})^{-1}=e^{-1}=e $ (or simply that $|a^{-1}|=|a|$).
- $a,b \in H \implies ab \in H$ because $(ab)^{12}=a^{12} b^{12}=ee=e$.

The last argument relies crucially on $G$ being abelian.

Comment: Note that $12$ plays no role here. Any fixed integer will do.

Answer (score 6):

Notice that $|g|$ divides $12$ if and only if $12g = 0$.
Because the map $f \colon G \to G$, $g \mapsto 12g$ is a group homomorphism it follows that $H = \ker f$ is a subgroup.

Comment: I haven't come across the terms "homomorphism" or "ker" in the book I'm reading, is there a way prove this specifically with order relationships?